# TWINE switched from Harlowe to sugarcube --> passage links are not working anymore

Tags: html, adventure, twine, sugarcube

Building an interactive Story in Twine 2.5.1, I've switched from Harlowe to Sugarcube since I feel more comfortable with the sugarcube 2.36.1. However, now the passages are not working anymore.

In the preview game the options are marked red. This only applies to some, not all. Those who are functioning, are still blue and link to the next passages. This is the error, when clicking on a red coded option: Error: the passage "investigation 2" does not exist.

Since the game has already over 200 chapters, a solution of not rewriting the whole game would be amazing or is it simply not possible to switch? Also the exported html has the same problem (itś not just the preview).

I hope there is a simple solution to this I just don't see at the moment. Please help me out. I'm really inexperienced in Twine so far.

Thank you so much and have a great weekend.
Amber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have used the standard passage linking form [[Passage Name]], it should be the same for both Harlowe and SugarCube.

If you used the *(link-goto: "Passage Name")* macro in Harlowe i.e: *(link-goto: "Enter the cellar", "Cellar")*

See: https://twine2.neocities.org/#macro_link-goto

Then these will need to be changed to the SugarCube equivalent macro *<<link [[Passage Name]]>>*

See: https://www.motoslave.net/sugarcube/2/docs/#macros-macro-link

Unfortunately, if you have used the macro form, then I don't think there is an easy option. You will have to manually rewrite **ALL** Harlowe macros to the SugarCube equivalents.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33473970)